# Typo3 Tree Import fail

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using Typo3 6.2 and I want move my Projekt to another Computer with Typo3 6.2 but I'm failing to import the tree structure ...

When I'm import a single page it works but when if the page has a subpages it doesnt work.

After I uploading a receive this Error:

[image: Upload Error]

"Possible error: pages:15 had no new id assigned to it. This indicates that the record was not added to database during import. Please check changelog!"

Here is the import file, maybe it just doesnt work on my system...

File [leist.t3d](http://www.datafile.com/d/TkRNMk56TXhNQT0F9)

**means**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but is sounds like a known bug:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/59055

Or more specific (copy pasted from that bug):

> When I change uniqid('NEW'); to uniqid('NEW', TRUE); in class
>   ImportExport the functional tests aren't failing and I assume
>   introduction extension is imported correctly (no errors in typo3.log).

(again not totally certain) but you might wanna patch it for testing or fetching a patched source for
/typo3/sysext/impexp/Classes/ImportExport.php

Comment: This is so ridiculous... I spent a whole day....but it worked for me thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, too.
In my case, I got an error message after enabling error messages, it was a missing field in table "pages", after a "DB compare", the import worked.